# Send Reply to email thread

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib, imaplib

I'm trying to reply to an email based on the following criteria:

Scan the inbox for unseen mails with specific Subject content, if there is mails that satisfy those criteria then: send back an reply message to the sender saying "something", if those criteria are not met then: send back an reply message to the sender saying "something".

This is what i came up with so far:

```
import imaplib
import email
import smtplib


username = 'sample@gmail.com'
password = 'xxxx'


imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
imap_server.login(username, password)

imap_server.select('INBOX')

result, data = imap_server.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')

email_ids = data[0].split()

for email_id in email_ids:

    result, data = imap_server.fetch(email_id, "(RFC822)")

    raw_email = data[0][1]

    email_message = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)

    subject = email_message["Subject"]

    if subject == "SOME SPECIFIC CONTENT":

        reply = email.message.EmailMessage()
        reply["To"] = email_message["From"]
        reply["Subject"] = "Re: " + email_message["Subject"]
        reply["In_Reply-To"] = email_message["From"]
              

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)

        server.sendmail(username, reply["In_Reply-To"], 'Subject: Criteria met\n\nThank you.')
        server.quit()

    else:

        
        reply = email.message.EmailMessage()
        reply['To'] = email_message['From']
        reply['Subject'] = "RE:" + email_message['Subject']
        reply["In_Reply-To"] = email_message["From"]
        

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)

        server.sendmail(username, reply["In_Reply-To"], 'Subject: Criteria not met\n\Thank you.')
        print('Sending email')
        server.quit()

imap_server.close()
```

It sends the email but without the desired thread, just sends a new email and not actually replying back to the sender.

Any suggestion on how to modify the code so it actually send an reply with the desired thread?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In-Reply-To should be set to the Message-Id of the replying email, not the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment mentions, you should use the Message-Id of the original message, not the sender address.

Also, you should obey `Reply-To:` and add `References:`.

```
        reply = email.message.EmailMessage()
        reply["To"] = email_message["Reply-To"] or email_message["From"]
        reply["Subject"] = "Re: " + email_message["Subject"]
        reply["In_Reply-To"] = email_message["Message-Id"]
        reply["References"] = (email_message["References"] or "") + " " + email_message["Message-Id"]
```

Properly speaking, the `References:` header should be trimmed from the middle if it's too long.

Some vendors have their own nonstandard threading extensions; in particular, Microsoft's `Thread-Id:` etc headers are probably best ignored.